# WPF binding selectedvalue datagrid to combobox

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, combobox, selectedvalue

I have a datagrid with databinding to a class with several properties. I would need to bind the selected row values to several combobox or textbox when I can alter the values (2 way binding so).
Imagine that the datagrid have list of Person with properties like Age and Name associated with 2 combobox where I can choose the values.

How can I make this binding of the selected value properties to the comboboxs?

Thanks in advance!

edit: I would prefer to this in the xaml if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the datagrid you need to specify the name of the control by using Name property.

```
<DataGrid Name= "dgPersons"/>
```

On the combobox you can refer the datagrid to bind the selected value.

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=dgPerosn,Path=SelectedItem.PersonId,Mode=TwoWay}/>
```